# Rails has_secure_password authentication errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
end
```

This is how someone can authenticate via API:

```
module Api
  class SessionsController < ApiController
    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        # some login logic
      else
        render json: {messages: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I pass an incorrect password, I get 401 Unauthorized as expected. However, `user.errors` is blank. How can I access `has_secure_password` authentication errors?

Comment: Can you not manually add `messages: "Invalid email or password"`? - You are not validating any attributes, only that the user can be authenticated. AFAIK `has_secure_password` provides validations on create of object but just returns false when user cannot be authenticated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only validation errors get populated in active record errors. Incorrect password is not a validation error. Why can't you set the message explicitly since the only possible error is email/password invalid

```
module Api
  class SessionsController < ApiController
    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
        # some login logic
      else
        render json: {messages: ["Invalid Email or Password"]}, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to do. In short, put a method (called `password_verified` in this example) on the User model that adds an error if `authenticate` fails.

```
# app/models/user.rb
def password_verified(password)
  verified = authenticate(password)
  errors.add(:password, 'is invalid') unless verified
  verified
end
```

Now, instead of calling `authenticate` call `password_verified`. Your example it would look like this:

```
module Api
  class SessionsController < ApiController
    def create
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
      # Here is where we call our wrapper method instead of authenticate
      if user && user.password_verified(params[:user][:password])
        # some login logic
      else
        render json: {messages: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is using ActiveModel::Errors just like custom validators are meant to do, so it's well documented (i.e. Rails Guides, ActiveRecord Validations, errors.add). Although, I put `password_verified` on the user model here, it can go anywhere like a service or concern.